# Publishing status: Rejected Play Store due to Sensitive Permission of SMS

Tags: android, permissions, sms, store, playback

My App was removed from play store due to SMS OTP related permission, now i upload new updated apk without any SMS permissions. but still they are rejecting my app with below msg stuff :

Based on our review, we found your app's expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler).

Play store show Previously Declared Permissions which was there in Removed apk, but now in case of new update, that dialog also shows. 
Even after submitting Use Case form, still they are giving me same reply.

Comment: see your email they must have provided a way how to get rid of that

Comment: unfortunately, they haven't.

Answer (score 3):

After lot of research, i figured out that problem seems in older uploded apk in Release section of play store console. They contains SMS permissions, so Use case dialog appears while publishing App.
So, update/publish new apk in Internal Test Track, Move to Alpha, Move to Beta, then finally move it to Production. 
May be you will get Use Case of Sensitive Permission dialog in Internal test track, Alpha and Beta, then select any random option in those use case for core functionality.
In Production, there'll be no any dialog for core functionality. And, it works.